# How to set optgroup in select2 using JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

How some items can be group in separate `optgroups`? Should be set in different `JSON` objects? There is no example in `select2` documentation. Any help or direction would be helpful.

Here is example code of `select` population:

`jQuery` code:

```
 var data = [
          { id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, 
          { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, 
          { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, 
          { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, 
          { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }
    ];

    $(".js-example-data-array").select2({
      data: data
    });
```

Comment: there is no example for this job in site, developer use '$(".js-source-states").html();' for fill them. and remove object after filling

Comment: so, there is no way for filling select only using JSON objects?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to set `children` attribute in your array to allow `optgroups`.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/8odneso7/13/

```js
var data = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'enhancement',
    children: [{
        id: 5,
        text: 'enhancement child1'
      },
      {
        id: 6,
        text: 'enhancement child2'

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'bug'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'duplicate'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'invalid'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    text: 'wontfix'
  }
];

$(".js-example-data-array").select2({
  data: data,
  width: 'auto'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-data-array">
</select>
```

Comment: Great! I've tested in my project and its working as expected! Thanks